# Canvas.toDataUrl sometimes truncated in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, libgdx

In the HTML5 version of my LibGDX game, *sometimes* `canvas.toDataUrl("image/png")` returns a truncated string yielding a black image.

```
CanvasElement canvas = ((GwtApplication)Gdx.app).getCanvasElement();
String dataUrl = canvas.toDataUrl("image/png");
Window.open(dataUrl, "_blank", "");
```

The odd part is that sometimes it works. When it does work I get a ~100KiB image as expected, and the new window opens with an address bar just saying "data:". I can send this to a webservice and translate from Base64 into the bytes of a proper PNG and OSX preview shows it just fine too.

When it *doesn't* work the new window shows a black image of the correct dimensions, and an address bar with Base64-encoded data in (starting `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN`...), but ending in an elipsis that appears to be rendered by the browser UI rather than three periods in the actual data string. The data in this case is ~31KiB. When I try transcoding this via my webservice, I get the same black rectangle.

I see this happen in both Chome and Firefox.

Any ideas? The code to get the canvas contents is very simple, so I can't see how I can be doing that wrong. I'm thinking either a bug in the browsers, or some kind of timing issue with LibGDX and rendering?

Comment: Maybe it's captured between glClear and the rendering? To check that, you could use another clear colour than black and see if you still get a black screen sometimes, or the new clear colour.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by LibGDX not preserving the drawing buffer. The LibGDX guys very kindly fixed this in a nightly build that is now available.

Updating to the latest build of `1.0-SNAPSHOT` and setting the below flag now works reliably:

```
    @Override
public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
    if(config == null)
    {
        config = new GwtApplicationConfiguration(1280, 960);
        config.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
    }

    return config; 
}
```